# How do I heal a specific limb?

Tags: fallout-4

How do I heal one of my limbs in Fallout 4? At various points a notification appears that one of my limbs is severely damaged, impairing my abilities. However, I can't figure out how to heal that limb.

On the Stats page of my Pip Boy I can see which limb is damaged, but I can't figure out how to select that limb and apply a stimpack to that limb. The only option I can find is to use a stimpack on my entire body, which (IIRC) doesn't do much to fix the limb that needs healing specifically.

Comment: I'm playing on Xbox One if that matters.

Comment: I've never had a problem stimpacking generally to heal ALL limbs. But I'm not 100% sure?

Comment: Limbs will also heal automatically when out of combat.  I haven't checked to see if they'll heal to 100% without food or stimpacks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't - unlike earlier Fallout games you can't heal specific limbs, a stimpack will just repair any that are damaged.